# Wrapper class for Tesseract API using c++

Tags: c++, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to create a wrapper class for TesseractAPI using c++. And I found an example from here
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/tesseract-ocr/7NIr71BQH8c

When i try to compile the program using following command

```
    g++ -o test TessApi.cpp -l /usr/local/include/tesseract/ -l /usr/include/leptonica/ -L /usr/local/lib/ -l tesseract
```

No luck, I have getting following error

```
    TessApi.cpp:1:21: fatal error: baseapi.h: No such file or directory
    compilation terminated.
```

Can anyone help me with this please.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are not specifying the command correctly. `-l` specifies a library to be linked against, while `-I` is used to specify an include directory. Try:

```
g++ -o test TessApi.cpp -I/usr/local/include/tesseract/ -I/usr/include/leptonica/ -L/usr/local/lib/ -ltesseract
```

assuming that Tesseract is actually installed in `/usr/local/`.